# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N21706' - Django

Tags: python, django, view

After searching I've found out that the problem is related to the ForeignKey. It is expecting to return the id but I want to use the tail number. I've tried many ways but I don't seem to understand how it works.

I'm doing a ForeignKey into the model of a different app. The two apps are called dispatch (app2) and add_acft (app1). The views that I'm having the errors on are on the dispatch app. Thanks in advance for anything you can do to help me understand.

**add_cft models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class AddAcft(models.Model):

    YEAR_CHOICES = []
    for r in range(1940,(datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
        YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))

    make = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=False,null=False)
    make_model = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=False,null=False)
    tail = models.CharField(max_length=7,blank=False,null=False)
    year = models.IntegerField(('year'),choices=YEAR_CHOICES,     default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    serial_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tail
```

**dispatch models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from add_acft import models as aircraft_models


shced_type_choices = (('rental','rental'), ('instruction','instruction'))


class Reservation(models.Model):
    res_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Created")
    reservation_type = models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=shced_type_choices, default="rental")
    tail = models.ForeignKey(aircraft_models.AddAcft)
    renter = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.renter

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("reservations:detail", kwargs={"res_number": self.res_number})
```

**dispatch views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from add_acft.models import AddAcft


from .forms import ReservationForm, CloseReservationForm
from .models import Reservation

def reservations_list(request):
    queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "List"

    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/list.html", context)

def reservations_detail(request, res_number=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Reservation, res_number=res_number)
    context = {
        "title": instance.renter,
        "instance": instance,

    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/details.html", context)


def reservations_create(request):
    ReservationForm.base_fields['tail'] =    forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AddAcft.objects.all())
    form = ReservationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Reservation Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
    "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/create.html", context)
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace please

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with that assignment to `ReservationForm.base_fields` - generally you should never modify that attribute - but without seeing the full error and traceback we can't help.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I'm using that one just to list the tail numbers and create a ModelChoiceField with what is already saved instead of having the user type it in. That part actually works. If I run for example by using: tail = models.CharField(max_length=10) (inside dispatch model) everything works. My problem is by trying to replace that with a foreign key to tail in the add_acf model. I'm out right now, I'll copy the error later today.

Comment: Following Daniel's advice I was able to fix it by removing what I had in ReservationForm.base_fields. After moving everything into their respective place everything worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just to change the following:

**Views:** Removed the base_fields part:

```
def reservations_create(request):
    form = ReservationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Reservation Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
    "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/create.html", context)
```